# should we always define interface and abstract classes, even when there will only be only 1 class extending them?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract, conceptual

should oneself always define interface and abstract classes always, even when there will only be only 1 class extending them ? I have been working on some small Java project for some time. I have always seen that they were always creating abstract classes and interfaces every other classes they were writing. But in almost every other case the interfaces were implemented by only one class and also the abstract classes were extended by only one another class. This is because there was no scope of extension  or implementation by multiple classes.
So as per my understanding we can have interfaces and abstract classes if we know that there will be lot of other classes going to make use of it. In above case I feel one should have directly written concrete classes. And in future if need be oneself can modify these classes and create interfaces etc and make use of it. Somehow I am 99% sure that my understanding over usage of polymorphism is not up to the mark. Please let me know the correct usage of these concepts.

Comment: While this is a good question, the answer depends on the specific context and is likely to result in opinion and discussion, which is off-topic for so.  Maybe better on [programmers.se].

Comment: If it helps to keep the code clean: yes. Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: The project you describe sounds like a textbook example of *overengineering*.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes and interfaces are meant if you will use multiple of them. If you are only planning on one class, you don't need either.

If at a later point you need two subclasses you could always convert your original class to an interface.

One thing to keep in mind is that it is safe to write interfaces and abstract classes. If the functionality is already known and a skeleton has already been made, it is easier to test your classes and it will prevent errors.

Comment: An addition to this: interfaces are perfectly reasonable for a single class for testing purposes (repositories come to mind).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel With modern frameworks like Mockito that is (thankfully) not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces and abstract classes make sense if you have several similar classes that implement/extend it. They also make sense if you currently have only one subclass but you know that you could add some more subclasses at some time.

But if you know exactly that there will never be any other similar class you shouldn't make use of them. That would only slow down the program.

Comment: it wouldn't slow down the program, it would only make it slightly larger

Answer (score 0):

**Interface and single implementation can make sense** if you want to provide an API to a 'client'.

What you will do is to design the **API** first (interfaces), then provide it to your client, without the implementation. I see two advantages :

- your client can work on his side, knowing all the existing methods in your API : work can be parallelized between your team and your client team.
- you don't have to provide him with implementation sources, that you want to keep confidential. Implementation can be provided in a separate jar, at runtime.

Also, if you are working on a system where you want to preserve **backward compatibility**, I would suggest you introduce interfaces as soon as possible in order not to get stuck later.

**Otherwise**, I would suggest you to introduce interfaces **only when you need them**, and rely on refactoring tools in order to change your code easily. This will lead you to someting easier to understand. Other developers will thank you for that.

Cheers